# Error when opening WFS layer in QGIS (Cannot do natural order without a primary key)

Tags: qgis, geoserver, layers, wfs

We want to open a Geoserver WFS layer in QGis but ending up with the error:
*Exception occurred while computing reprojected bounds
java.io.IOExceptionCannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes*

The WFS layer is pointing to a view that is getting its data from one table which has a primary key consisting out of 2 columns

- Column identificatie, number 1 in the view which is a "character varying(200)"
- Column layer_nr, number 9 in the view which is an integer.

Because the view doesn't know what the primary key is we figured out that we have to specify the primary key in the public.gt_pk_metadata.
[image: Our public.gt_pk_metadata set up]

Can someone help us how we can get rid of the error message?

Note

- After making the changes we restart Tomcat and recreate the layer again and loaded the WFS layer in QGIS again
- We created gt_pk_metadata in the public schema, like described over [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html)
- We tried with and without mentioning the gt_pk_metadata table name in the store configuration in Geoserver
- We assume that pk_column_idx is NOT a zero based index
- We only want to view data not inserting new data through WFS

To reproduce

```
------ Creation of my_table
*CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS geoserver.my_table
(
    identificatie character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    column_two character varying(110) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    column_three character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    column_four character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    column_five text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    column_six date,
    column_seven text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    column_eight character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    layer_nr integer NOT NULL,
    column_ten character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    geom geometry(Polygon) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_my_table PRIMARY KEY (identificatie, layer_nr)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);
------- Creation of my_view
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW geoserver.my_view
 AS
 SELECT my_table.identificatie,
    my_table.column_two,
    my_table.column_three,
    my_table.column_four,
    my_table.column_five,
    my_table.column_six,
    my_table.column_seven,
    my_table.column_eight,
    my_table.layer_nr,
    my_table.column_ten,
    my_table.geom
   FROM geoserver.my_table;*
```

Log file:

```
10:49:08 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getCapabilities
    acceptVersions:
        version[0] = 2.0.0version[0] = 1.1.0version[0] = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = https://my_url/geoserver/
    namespace = IMNa_IMNa
    service = WFS
10:49:10 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
10:49:10 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: describeFeatureType
    service = WFS
    version = 2.0.0
    baseUrl = https://my_url/geoserver/
    typeName[0] = {IMNa_IMNa}my_view
    outputFormat = application/gml+xml; version=3.2
10:49:11 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
10:49:11 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
10:49:11 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "geoserver"."my_view" LIMIT 1) gt_limited_
10:49:11 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
10:49:11 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
*
    abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.QueryTypeImpl@526ac84a (handle: null) (abstractProjectionClause: null, abstractSelectionClause: null, abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{IMNa_IMNa}my_view]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
    abstractQueryExpression[0]:
        typeNames[0] = {IMNa_IMNa}my_view
        srsName = urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992
10:49:11 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - building schema for schema: IMNa_IMNa
10:49:11 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
10:49:11 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) FROM "geoserver"."my_view"
10:49:11 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
10:49:11 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
10:49:11 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
10:49:11 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
10:49:11 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while computing reprojected bounds
    at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.getBounds(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:181)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:175)
    ... 113 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:650)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.sort(JDBCDataStore.java:3660)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.selectSQL(JDBCDataStore.java:3493)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:617)
    ... 119 more

10:49:12 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "geoserver"."my_view" LIMIT 1) gt_limited_

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:12 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
*
abstractSelectionClause: null, abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{IMNa_IMNa}my_view]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
    abstractQueryExpression[0]:
        typeNames[0] = {IMNa_IMNa}my_view
        srsName = urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - building schema for schema: IMNa_IMNa

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) FROM "geoserver"."my_view"
```

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:12 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:12 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:12 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.

10:49:12 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
at org.geotools.xsd.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while computing reprojected bounds
at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.getBounds(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:181)
... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:175)
... 113 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:650)
... 117 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.sort(JDBCDataStore.java:3660)
... 119 more

10:49:12 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "geoserver"."my_view" LIMIT 1) gt_limited_

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
10:49:12 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getFeature
service = WFS
*
abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.QueryTypeImpl@27067f73 (handle: null) (abstractProjectionClause: null, abstractSelectionClause: null, abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{IMNa_IMNa}my_view]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
abstractQueryExpression[0]:
typeNames[0] = {IMNa_IMNa}my_view
srsName = urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992

10:49:12 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - building schema for schema: IMNa_IMNa

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) FROM "geoserver"."my_view"

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:13 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:13 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:13 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.

10:49:13 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
at org.geotools.xsd.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while computing reprojected bounds
at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.getBounds(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:181)
... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:175)
... 113 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:650)
... 117 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.sort(JDBCDataStore.java:3660)
... 119 more

10:49:13 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "geoserver"."my_view" LIMIT 1) gt_limited_

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:13 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getFeature
service = WFS
*
null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
abstractQueryExpression[0]:
typeNames[0] = {IMNa_IMNa}my_view
srsName = urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - building schema for schema: IMNa_IMNa

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) FROM "geoserver"."my_view"

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:13 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:13 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:13 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:13 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.

10:49:13 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
at org.geotools.xsd.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:103)
at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingWalker$BindingExecutionChain.execute(BindingWalker.java:218)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while computing reprojected bounds
at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.getBounds(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:181)
... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:175)
... 113 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:650)
... 117 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.sort(JDBCDataStore.java:3660)
... 119 more

10:49:16 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo

10:49:16 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
10:49:16 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName

10:49:16 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
10:49:16 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:16 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:16 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "geoserver"."my_view" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-259859.20125879566 295911.7997564386, -259859.20125879566 647856.028799076, 543089.0741542695 647856.028799076, 543089.0741542695 295911.7997564386, -259859.20125879566 295911.7997564386))', 28992) LIMIT 1000000) gt_limited_

10:49:16 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:16 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getFeature
service = WFS
version = 2.0.0
baseUrl = https://my_url/geoserver/
count = 1000000
outputFormat = application/gml+xml; version=3.2
resolve = none
resolveDepth = *
resolveTimeout = 300
resultType = results
startIndex = 0
abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.QueryTypeImpl@4d796400 (handle: null) (abstractProjectionClause: null, abstractSelectionClause: [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[-259859.20125879566 : 543089.0741542695, 295911.7997564386 : 647856.028799076] DefaultProjectedCRS[EPSG:Amersfoort / RD New] AXIS["Easting", EAST] AXIS["Northing", NORTH] ], abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{IMNa_IMNa}my_view]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)

10:49:16 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - building schema for schema: IMNa_IMNa

10:49:16 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:16 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:16 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:16 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName

10:49:16 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression

10:49:16 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:16 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:16 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:16 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.

10:49:16 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
at org.geotools.xsd.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while computing reprojected bounds
at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.getBounds(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:181)
... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:175)
... 113 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:650)
... 117 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.sort(JDBCDataStore.java:3660)
... 119 more

10:49:17 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo

10:49:17 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:17 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName

10:49:17 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression

10:49:17 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:17 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:17 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "geoserver"."my_view" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-259859.20125879566 295911.7997564386, -259859.20125879566 647856.028799076, 543089.0741542695 647856.028799076, 543089.0741542695 295911.7997564386, -259859.20125879566 295911.7997564386))', 28992) LIMIT 1000000) gt_limited_

10:49:17 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:17 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getFeature
service = WFS
version = 2.0.0
baseUrl = https://my_url/geoserver/
count = 1000000
outputFormat = application/gml+xml; version=3.2
resolve = none
resolveDepth = *
resolveTimeout = 300
resultType = results
startIndex = 0
abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.QueryTypeImpl@5663b6ce (handle: null) (abstractProjectionClause: null, abstractSelectionClause: [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[-259859.20125879566 : 543089.0741542695, 295911.7997564386 : 647856.028799076] DefaultProjectedCRS[EPSG:Amersfoort / RD New] AXIS["Easting", EAST] AXIS["Northing", NORTH] ], abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{IMNa_IMNa}my_view]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
abstractQueryExpression[0]:
abstractSelectionClause = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[-259859.20125879566 : 543089.0741542695, 295911.7997564386 : 647856.028799076] DefaultProjectedCRS[EPSG:Amersfoort / RD New] AXIS["Easting", EAST] AXIS["Northing", NORTH] ]
typeNames[0] = {IMNa_IMNa}my_view
srsName = urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992
filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[-259859.20125879566 : 543089.0741542695, 295911.7997564386 : 647856.028799076] DefaultProjectedCRS[EPSG:Amersfoort / RD New] AXIS["Easting", EAST] AXIS["Northing", NORTH] ]

10:49:17 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - building schema for schema: IMNa_IMNa

10:49:17 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:17 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:17 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:17 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName

10:49:17 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression

10:49:17 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:17 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:17 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
10:49:17 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.

10:49:17 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
at org.geotools.xsd.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while computing reprojected bounds
at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.getBounds(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:181)
... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:175)
... 113 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:650)
... 117 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.sort(JDBCDataStore.java:3660)
... 119 more

10:49:18 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:18 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName

10:49:18 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "geoserver"."my_view" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-259859.20125879566 295911.7997564386, -259859.20125879566 647856.028799076, 543089.0741542695 647856.028799076, 543089.0741542695 295911.7997564386, -259859.20125879566 295911.7997564386))', 28992) LIMIT 1000000) gt_limited_

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:18 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getFeature
service = WFS
version = 2.0.0
baseUrl = https://my_url/geoserver/
count = 1000000
outputFormat = application/gml+xml; version=3.2
resolve = none
resolveDepth = *
resolveTimeout = 300
resultType = results
startIndex = 0
abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.QueryTypeImpl@4f0b94cc (handle: null) (abstractProjectionClause: null, abstractSelectionClause: [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[-259859.20125879566 : 543089.0741542695, 295911.7997564386 : 647856.028799076] DefaultProjectedCRS[EPSG:Amersfoort / RD New] AXIS["Easting", EAST] AXIS["Northing", NORTH] ], abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{IMNa_IMNa}my_view]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
abstractQueryExpression[0]:
abstractSelectionClause = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[-259859.20125879566 : 543089.0741542695, 295911.7997564386 : 647856.028799076] DefaultProjectedCRS[EPSG:Amersfoort / RD New] AXIS["Easting", EAST] AXIS["Northing", NORTH] ]
typeNames[0] = {IMNa_IMNa}my_view
srsName = urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992
filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[-259859.20125879566 : 543089.0741542695, 295911.7997564386 : 647856.028799076] DefaultProjectedCRS[EPSG:Amersfoort / RD New] AXIS["Easting", EAST] AXIS["Northing", NORTH] ]

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - building schema for schema: IMNa_IMNa

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:18 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName

10:49:18 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:18 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.

10:49:18 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
at org.geotools.xsd.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:103)
at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingWalker$BindingExecutionChain.execute(BindingWalker.java:218)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while computing reprojected bounds
at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.getBounds(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:181)
... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:175)
... 113 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:650)
... 117 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.sort(JDBCDataStore.java:3660)
... 119 more

10:49:18 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:18 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName

10:49:18 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "geoserver"."my_view" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-259859.20125879566 295911.7997564386, -259859.20125879566 647856.028799076, 543089.0741542695 647856.028799076, 543089.0741542695 295911.7997564386, -259859.20125879566 295911.7997564386))', 28992) LIMIT 1000000) gt_limited_

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:18 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getFeature
service = WFS

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - building schema for schema: IMNa_IMNa

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:18 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName

10:49:18 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:18 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.

10:49:18 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
at org.geotools.xsd.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:103)
... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:175)
... 113 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:650)
... 117 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.sort(JDBCDataStore.java:3660)
... 119 more

10:49:18 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION

10:49:18 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName

10:49:18 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "geoserver"."my_view" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-259859.20125879566 295911.7997564386, -259859.20125879566 647856.028799076, 543089.0741542695 647856.028799076, 543089.0741542695 295911.7997564386, -259859.20125879566 295911.7997564386))', 28992) LIMIT 1000000) gt_limited_

10:49:18 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION

10:49:18 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getFeature
service = WFS
version = 2.0.0
baseUrl = https://my_url/geoserver/
*
abstractQueryExpression[0]:
abstractSelectionClause = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[-259859.20125879566 : 543089.0741542695, 295911.7997564386 : 647856.028799076] DefaultProjectedCRS[EPSG:Amersfoort / RD New] AXIS["Easting", EAST] AXIS["Northing", NORTH] ]
typeNames[0] = {IMNa_IMNa}my_view
filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[-259859.20125879566 : 543089.0741542695, 295911.7997564386 : 647856.028799076] DefaultProjectedCRS[EPSG:Amersfoort / RD New] AXIS["Easting", EAST] AXIS["Northing", NORTH] ]

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

10:49:18 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.

Comment: I think the indexes should be 0 and 1 as they are the order to stick the keys together not where they are in the table (GeoServer can work that out)

Comment: Thank you @IanTurton for your comment, We tried to use  0 and 1 but also 1 and 2 for pk_column_idx. But both didn't help

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, We added the logging (GeoTools_Developer) in the description of the post. We looked at it but couldn't find the cause.

Comment: I can't see any log file, we need to see the queries being sent to the database

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, sorry, there was a character limit. It has been added now,